# How to call python script in other folder without prepending `python`?

Tags: windows, terminal, python, file-association

I have a small (self-written) python script located in, let's say, `C:\dummy\myscript.py`.
In my **Windows 7** terminal, I can call this script with either one of the following three commands. They all work.

```
C:\dummy>python myscript.py
C:\dummy>myscript.py
C:\dummy>myscript
```

I understand that the latter two commands work out fine because of the correct `assoc .py=Python.File` setting on my system(see [here](http://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html#executing-scripts))

However, when I am in another folder, say, `C:\dummy\subfolder\`, it only works when I prepend the python executable.

```
C:\dummy\subfolder>python ../myscript.py

C:\dummy\subfolder>../myscript.py                         <-- doesn't work
'..' is not recgnized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\dummy\subfolder>../myscript                            <-- doesn't work
'..' is not recgnized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Why doesn't it work in the other two cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using *nix path delimiters. Use ..\myscript.py, not ../myscript.py. The Python program is smart enough to accept either.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\localization>../notepad++.exe
'..' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\localization>..\notepad++.exe
[ this one launched the app as expected ]
```

Comment: Ah rats, of course!

Comment: @Rabarberski Just a note that this is the case for CMD; PowerShell can take either delimiter.